# Rasa core agent.handle_channel

Tags: python, sockets, operating-system, agent, rasa-core

I am trying to do a slack integration for my bot. this is my python script that will run the bot on slack:

```
from rasa_core.channels import HttpInputChannel
from rasa_core.agent import Agent
from rasa_core.interpreter import RasaNLUInterpreter
from rasa_slack_connector import SlackInput


nlu_interpreter = RasaNLUInterpreter('./model/nlu/default/weathernlu')
agent = Agent.load('./model/dialogue', interpreter = nlu_interpreter)

input_channel = SlackInput('*******', #app verification token
                            '*******', # bot verification token
                            '********', # slack verification token
                            True)

agent.handle_channel(HttpInputChannel(5006, '/', input_channel))
```

My problem is everytime I close the app and try to run it, i can't use the same port. I started with 5000 and you can see I reached 5006 because I had to change it everytime. If I try to run it using the same port I get this error:

> OSError: [WinError 10048] Only one usage of each socket address
>   (protocol/networ k address/port) is normally permitted

Can anyone explain what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

You should check which port are binded using the cmd [netstat](https://commandwindows.com/netstat.htm) and also check the process still running on your machine.

Closing your app might not kill the process therefore your previous instance of your app may still use the ports.